# Имитация ручного ввода текста selenium webdriver

Tags: c#

Собственно как сделать имитацию ручного ввода текста в selenium webdriver, по сколько метод SendKeys не подходит, он вводит строку одним разом, а нужно по букве

Comment: Вызови его несколько раз?

Comment: Если несколько раз вызывать то будет просто замена строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
var myString = "123";

var element = driver.FindElementById("MyId");

for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
{
    element.SendKeys(myString[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Возможно нужна будет задержка между вызовами метода SendKeys.

Comment: 1. StringBuilder не нужен. 2. Насколько я помню, `SendKeys` асинхронный, поэтому его надо ждать. 3. С какого вообще перепуга стрингбилдер в цикле создаётся?